# ERC20Snapshot.sol not to be found in ^0.8.20

Tags: erc-20, openzeppelin

I couldn't find the ERC20Snapshot.sol in extensions for the newest update. Has snapshot functionality been removed permanently from the format?

Answer (score 1):

ERC20Snapshot was replaced with ERC20Votes back in May 2023. You can find discussion about it in this commit: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/commit/15c5c7179555ee46baf839db003029f4b2bcb470

Comment: Thank you Vas Treck